# How to sort Norwegian text on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, localization, postgresql-9.2

I'm having trouble sorting Norwegian text column in Postgres.
My environment:

```
db=# select version();
PostgreSQL 9.2.14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit
```

the database is hosted on RedHat Openshift.

when running `>locale` command I get:

- locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
- locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
- LANG=en_US.UTF-8
- LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
- LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_ALL=

**edit

```
db=#\l
          Name           |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 db                      | myadminUser  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

this is what I tried, 
this sql shows the default sort is incorrect:

```
db=# select * from unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c','d','A','B','C','å','ø','z','Z','Ø']) as t1 order by t1;
```

result: **a
 A
 å
 b
 B
 c
 C
 d
 ø
 Ø
 z
 Z**

(I think this sort order is even wrong for English, Capital 'A' should come before 'a' isn't it ?)

then I tried :

```
db=# CREATE COLLATION nor (LOCALE = 'nn_NO.utf8');
```

and the same statement from before:

```
db=# select * from unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c','d','A','B','C','å','ø','z','Z','Ø']) as t1 order by t1 collate nor;
```

Now the result is:  **A
 a
 B
 b
 C
 c
 d
 Z
 z
 Ø
 ø
 å**

This looked really good, I thought I'm done.. BUT then I tried:

```
db=# select * from unnest(ARRAY['aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','åååå','øøøø','zzzz','ZZZZ','ØØØØ']) as t1 order by t1 collate nor;
```

result: **BBBB
 bbbb
 CCCC
 cccc
 dddd
 ZZZZ
 zzzz
 ØØØØ
 øøøø
 AAAA
 aaaa
 åååå**

what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is correct. In Norwegian "aa" is the spelling of "å" and it should go at the end.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85

> Correct alphabetization in Danish and Norwegian places Å as the last
> letter in the alphabet, the sequence being Æ, Ø, Å. This is also true
> for the alternative spelling "Aa". Unless manually corrected, sorting
> algorithms of programs localised for Danish or Norwegian will place
> e.g., Aaron after Zorro.